# Add image when creating content with Devel Content Generate?

Tags: media, debugging

I used to use [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) to generate nodes content for developing purposes. It works fine but it doesn't add images to the created nodes even though the content type has an image field.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it a standard image field? I've never had this problem, Devel Generate has always added images without issue for me

Comment: have you checked the permissions at sites/default/files (or wherever the image field uploads to)?  Is it writable?

Comment: I've done this before and I never had this problem. I think there was a checkbox input to check "Add images if the content type has an image field" somewhere...